# Javascript thinks 8 is larger than 12

Tags: javascript

```
function function1() {
  arr = document.getElementById("textfield").value;
  arr = arr.split(",");
  length = arr.length;
  largestNum = -9999;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > largestNum) {
      largestNum = arr[i];
    }
  }
  alert("Largest number: " + largestNum);
}
```

can someone tell me what the hell is going on here, i have no idea why it's giving me 8 instead of 12

http://jsfiddle.net/qkLpA/15/

edit - fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/qkLpA/12/

Comment: javascript might think the variables are strings, just brainstorming. add 9 to the array and try it out.

Comment: That's exactly what is happening. I'm too lazy to give a proper answer, though.

Comment: The answer: Because "8" *is* larger than "12".

Comment: Try parseInt(arr[i], 10) instead of arr[i], also: it seems like you are not reading the variable numIndex anywhere, might as well delete it.

Comment: replace `arr[i]` with `arr[i]*1` everyplace and see what happens.

Comment: @MichaelW it was for another function, deleted now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're splitting a string, so each element of the resulting array will be a string. When you compare strings, it goes character-by-character, and 8 is larger than 1, so it never goes on to the 2.

The solution is to convert the items into numbers after splitting it:

```
arr = arr.split(",").map(function(s) { return parseInt(s, 10); });
```

If the `map` is confusing, you could also be less fancy and just use a `for` loop to convert them:

```
arr = arr.split(",");
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = parseInt(arr[i], 10);
}
```

You may also want to consider using `-Infinity` as the initial `largestNum` rather than `-9999`.

Comment: yes that works, what do you mean by "8 is larger than 1, so it never goes on to the 2"?

Comment: @user2782160: If I'm comparing two strings as I would words in a dictionary, I start at the first character. If they're different, whichever one's character comes first in the alphabet goes first; otherwise, I move on to the next letter. If we're comparing `8` and `12`, the first characters are `8` and `1`. Clearly, `8` comes after `1`, so it's the greater one. Since they're strings, it compares them as text, not as numbers.

Answer (score 3):

There's a much shorter way to get the largest humber:

```
function function1() {
  var arr = document.getElementById("textfield").value;
  arr = arr.split(",");
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  alert("Largest number: " + max);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CQc7z/)

Comment: i wasnt aware Math.max existed, i will choose icktoofay's answer but this one is really helpful too

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `.split()` of the textfield string, creates an array of strings and not numbers. As a consequence, your comparison `if (arr[i] > largestNum)` in the for loop, is in reality a lexicographical comparison of strings, instead of a numerical comparison of integers, as you might have thought. That is why the "8" is larger than the "12".

You can confirm this in [the updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkLpA/14/) which converts the strings to integers before comparing.